# Java Mockito- how to mock uncertain number of parameter method

Tags: java, mockito

I try to use Mockito to mock the `getDeclaredMethod()` of java.
but the parameter of this method is un-certain. how to mock such method?

```
public Method getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class... parameterTypes) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ArgumentMatchers.any()](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any())

> Matches anything, including nulls and varargs.

**Example**

```
when(mockedObject.getDeclaredMethod(anyString(),any())).thenReturn("element");
```

In your case

```
when(mockedObject.getDeclaredMethod(anyString(), (Class<?>)any())).thenReturn("element");
```

And also [anyVararg()](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyVararg()) but which is Deprecated. as of 2.1.0

Comment: yes, thanks, the correct answer is `when(mockClass.getDeclaredMethod(anyString(), (Class<?>) any())`